# organizing javascript files for better obfuscation

Tags: javascript, global-variables, obfuscation

```
utilities.js:
function log(message)
{
....
}

module1.js
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function()
{
  log("module1 is loaded");
});

module2.js
YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function()
{
  log("module2 is loaded");
});
```

For the page request I would first load utilities.js and then module1.js and module2.js

Now when I try to obfuscate these files, references to "log" in the modules would not be obfuscated since it is an implied global.

I would like to keep the module files separate(though served for the same page) for better readability and maintenance. And the functions in utilities.js would also be used for other pages.

How can I better organize these files in order to improve obfuscation?

Answer (score 0):

Place your code in self execution anonymous functions:

```
(function(){
    YAHOO.util.Event.onDOMReady(function() {
        log("module2 is loaded");
    });
})();
```

So when your code will be obfuscating global functions and variables will still have their *original* names.

Comment: He will search your scoped variables and obfuscate them. And didn't obfuscate global variables. If function log defined outside the scope obfuscator wouldn't touch them

Comment: You can't that way. if you put the log inside a anonymous function that don't return nothing, it will only exist in the scope of that function.

Comment: that exactly what I dont want, I want the obfuscator to resolve the "log" function and there by obfucate it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like to use the RequireJS: http://requirejs.org/

It's a framework to load modules, and you can return a collection or object to use, and keep all your modules in individual scopes.